# Restart/refresh onCreateView when ViewPager shows a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have the following code to create a viewpager with fragments:

```
// Create tabs for viewpager
    FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
            .add(R.string.tab_stuff, Stuff.class)
            .add(R.string.tab_profile, Profile.class)
            .create());
// Give the viewpager an adapter
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I also give the user the option to change the current page on the viewpager with a menu on the drawer:

```
// Navigation view listener
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView
            .OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                // Item: shows stuff and then closes the drawer
                case R.id.navdrawer_stuff:

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
```

The tricksy things comes when the Fragment is attached and on the OnCreateView method happens this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Check if user is logged in and subbed
    logged = Prefs.getBoolean(LOGGED, false);
    subbed = Prefs.getBoolean(SUB, false);
    meal = Prefs.getBoolean(DAY_DIET, false);
    email = Prefs.getString(USERMAIL, "");

    // If user is logged and subbed
    if (logged && subbed) {
        // Inflate the proper layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.diets_user_subbed,
                container,
                false
        );
        try {
            currentDayMeal(email);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        checkMealsListener(view);
        return view;
    } else if (logged) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.no_sub,
                container,
                false
        );
        return view;
    } else {
        View view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.no_sub_no_reg,
                container,
                false
        );
        return view;
    }
}
```

Now, all of these work like a charm, until I change the values of logged or subbed and the OnCreateView is no longer checking what layout to load. It works if I close the app and restart it, but once it´s opened, it won´t re-check.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create in yours Fragment method to change yours layout. I.e. it must remove/add some views from root layout, that you can get by `Fragment#getView()`.
2. Make fragment to react when preferences changes. For it add `onSharedPreferenceChanged`. In it call fragments method from 1.

   ```
   public class FragmentsClassName extends Fragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
   {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           ....
           PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_in_swipe, container, false);
           update(v);
           return v;
       }

       private void update(View v)
       {
           //TODO update layout here
       }

       @Override
       public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
       {
           Log.i("log", "onSharedPreferenceChanged with key: " + key);
           if (!isAdded())
           {
               return;
           }
           update(getView());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry but, could you give me an example?